# Debian not using the whole monitor in All-In-One PC

Tags: linux, graphics, display, resolution

I installed Debian to dual boot with Windows 7 on this old Sony VAIO VGC-JS110J that I've had for years. I'm pretty new to Linux so please bare with me. I decided to use the Stable amd64 version with LXDE and non-free firmware.

I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` as soon as it was fully installed. The display was 1600x1200 60Hz when it was fully booted up and logged in, but an inch of the screen on the right was not being used and the bottom part of the display was offscreen by a bit (taskbar wasn't showing). I set the resolution to 1600x1050 59 Hz, which seems to fit usable portion of the screen.

[image: All-In-One PC]

I've looked everywhere, and I can't seem to find anything that fixes this. I really want to get into using Linux, but I'm stumped with this problem. How can I get Debian to fully utilize the screen?

Additional Info:

Windows 7 64-bit works fine with a 1680x1050 59Hz resolution.

`xrandr -q` outputs: (I created 1600x1050_59.00)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1600x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1600x1200     60.00 +
   1600x1050_59.00  59.00* 
VGA-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94
```

`lshw -c video`:

```
  *-display:0               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:fe400000-fe7fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:ec00(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe800000-fe8fffff
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[  1244.821] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[  1244.821] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1244.821] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[  1244.821] Current Operating System: Linux debian 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64
[  1244.821] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=f09f044d-6a4b-47c4-8da1-a0fce2ff092c ro quiet
[  1244.821] Build Date: 16 October 2017  08:19:45AM
[  1244.821] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[  1244.821] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  1244.821]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1244.821] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1244.822] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Dec  2 11:05:27 2017
[  1244.822] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1244.822] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1244.822] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1244.822] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1244.822] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1244.822] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1244.823] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1244.823] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1244.823] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1244.823] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1244.823] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1244.823]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1244.823] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[  1244.823] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1244.823] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1244.823] (II) Loader magic: 0x55bfd01b4e00
[  1244.823] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1244.823]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1244.823]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[  1244.823]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  1244.823]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  1244.824] (++) using VT number 7

[  1244.824] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[  1244.825] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1244.840] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:2e22:104d:9044 rev 3, Mem @ 0xfe400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000ec00/8, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1244.841] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:1) 8086:2e23:104d:9044 rev 3, Mem @ 0xfe800000/1048576
[  1244.841] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1244.841] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1244.843] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1244.843]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1244.843]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  1244.843] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1244.843] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1244.843] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[  1244.843] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1244.844] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  1244.844] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  1244.844] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1244.844]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.19.2
[  1244.844]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1244.844]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  1244.844] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1244.844] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1244.844] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1244.845]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.4.4
[  1244.845]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1244.845]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  1244.845] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1244.845] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  1244.845] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1244.845]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 2.3.4
[  1244.845]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1244.845]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  1244.845] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  1244.845] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  1244.845] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  1244.855] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[  1244.855] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  1244.855] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1244.855] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1244.855] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1244.855] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1244.855]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 0.0.2
[  1244.855]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  1244.855] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[  1244.856] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[  1244.856] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1244.856] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[  1244.856] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1244.856] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[  1244.856] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[  1244.856] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[  1244.863] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1244.863]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1244.863]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1244.863] (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
[  1244.880] (II) glamor: EGL version 1.4 (DRI2):
[  1244.885] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[  1244.986] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 has no monitor section
[  1245.136] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[  1245.234] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output LVDS-1
[  1245.234] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS-1
[  1245.234] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 -hsync -vsync (75.0 kHz eP)
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA-1
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "848x480"x60.0   33.75  848 864 976 1088  480 486 494 517 +hsync +vsync (31.0 kHz e)
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 connected
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 connected
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Using sloppy heuristic for initial modes
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 using initial mode 1600x1200 +0+0
[  1245.388] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 using initial mode 1024x768 +0+0
[  1245.388] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  1245.388] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  1245.388] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  1245.388] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  1245.388] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  1245.389] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1245.389]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  1245.389]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1245.389] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  1245.389] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  1245.389] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1245.389] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[  1245.389] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  1245.389] (II) Unloading vesa
[  1245.389] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  1245.534] (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
[  1245.534] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[  1245.534] (II) modeset(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[  1245.535] (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
[  1245.535] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[  1245.535] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[  1245.535] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965
[  1245.535] (--) RandR disabled
[  1245.539] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es{,2}_profile
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[  1245.548] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[  1245.548] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[  1245.551] (II) modeset(0): Damage tracking initialized
[  1245.551] (II) modeset(0): Setting screen physical size to 423 x 317
[  1245.612] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event5)
[  1245.612] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1245.612] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[  1245.612] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[  1245.614] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1245.614]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.23.0
[  1245.614]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1245.614]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[  1245.614] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  1245.614] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1245.614] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[  1245.614] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.615] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.615] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[  1245.632] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input10/event5"
[  1245.632] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[  1245.632] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1245.632] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1245.633] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.633] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[  1245.634] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sony Vaio Keys (/dev/input/event6)
[  1245.634] (**) Sony Vaio Keys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1245.634] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sony Vaio Keys'
[  1245.634] (**) Sony Vaio Keys: always reports core events
[  1245.634] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[  1245.634] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.635] (II) input device 'Sony Vaio Keys', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.635] (II) input device 'Sony Vaio Keys', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[  1245.648] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/SNY5001:00/input/input11/event6"
[  1245.648] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sony Vaio Keys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[  1245.648] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1245.648] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1245.648] (II) input device 'Sony Vaio Keys', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.648] (II) input device 'Sony Vaio Keys', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[  1245.649] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sony Vaio Jogdial (/dev/input/event7)
[  1245.649] (**) Sony Vaio Jogdial: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1245.649] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sony Vaio Jogdial'
[  1245.649] (**) Sony Vaio Jogdial: always reports core events
[  1245.649] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[  1245.649] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.650] (II) input device 'Sony Vaio Jogdial', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.650] (II) input device 'Sony Vaio Jogdial', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[  1245.664] (II) libinput: Sony Vaio Jogdial: needs a virtual subdevice
[  1245.664] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/SNY5001:00/input/input12/event7"
[  1245.664] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sony Vaio Jogdial" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[  1245.664] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1245.664] (**) Sony Vaio Jogdial: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1245.664] (**) Sony Vaio Jogdial: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1245.664] (**) Sony Vaio Jogdial: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1245.665] (II) input device 'Sony Vaio Jogdial', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.665] (II) input device 'Sony Vaio Jogdial', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[  1245.665] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sony Vaio Jogdial (/dev/input/mouse1)
[  1245.666] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1245.666] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1245.666] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[  1245.666] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1245.666] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[  1245.666] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1245.666] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[  1245.666] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.667] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.667] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[  1245.680] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input9/event4"
[  1245.680] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[  1245.680] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1245.680] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1245.681] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.681] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[  1245.682] (II) config/udev: Adding input device UVC Camera (05ca:183d) (/dev/input/event13)
[  1245.682] (**) UVC Camera (05ca:183d): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1245.682] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'UVC Camera (05ca:183d)'
[  1245.682] (**) UVC Camera (05ca:183d): always reports core events
[  1245.682] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event13"
[  1245.682] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.683] (II) input device 'UVC Camera (05ca:183d)', /dev/input/event13 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.683] (II) input device 'UVC Camera (05ca:183d)', /dev/input/event13 is a keyboard
[  1245.712] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb6/6-3/6-3:1.0/input/input18/event13"
[  1245.712] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "UVC Camera (05ca:183d)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[  1245.712] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1245.712] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1245.713] (II) input device 'UVC Camera (05ca:183d)', /dev/input/event13 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.713] (II) input device 'UVC Camera (05ca:183d)', /dev/input/event13 is a keyboard
[  1245.713] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Digital PCBeep (/dev/input/event8)
[  1245.713] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1245.714] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1245.714] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[  1245.714] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1245.714] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1245.715] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line (/dev/input/event10)
[  1245.715] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1245.715] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1245.715] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[  1245.715] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1245.716] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1245.717] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[  1245.717] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1245.717] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard'
[  1245.717] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: always reports core events
[  1245.717] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[  1245.717] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.718] (II) input device 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.718] (II) input device 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[  1245.748] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:04CA:0050.0005/input/input5/event0"
[  1245.748] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[  1245.748] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1245.748] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1245.749] (II) input device 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.749] (II) input device 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[  1245.750] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[  1245.750] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1245.750] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard'
[  1245.750] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: always reports core events
[  1245.750] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[  1245.750] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.751] (II) input device 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.751] (II) input device 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[  1245.780] (II) libinput: Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: needs a virtual subdevice
[  1245.780] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:04CA:0050.0006/input/input6/event1"
[  1245.780] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[  1245.780] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1245.780] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1245.780] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1245.780] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1245.781] (II) input device 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.781] (II) input device 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[  1245.782] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/event2)
[  1245.782] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[  1245.782] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Receiver'
[  1245.782] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: always reports core events
[  1245.782] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[  1245.782] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.840] (II) input device 'Logitech USB Receiver', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  1245.840] (II) input device 'Logitech USB Receiver', /dev/input/event2 is a pointer caps
[  1245.868] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:046D:C537.0007/input/input7/event2"
[  1245.868] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Receiver" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[  1245.868] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1245.868] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1245.868] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1245.868] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1245.928] (II) input device 'Logitech USB Receiver', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[  1245.928] (II) input device 'Logitech USB Receiver', /dev/input/event2 is a pointer caps
[  1245.929] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  1245.929] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1245.929] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1245.930] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/event3)
[  1245.931] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1245.931] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Receiver'
[  1245.931] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: always reports core events
[  1245.931] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  1245.931] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  1245.932] (II) input device 'Logitech USB Receiver', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.932] (II) input device 'Logitech USB Receiver', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[  1245.968] (II) libinput: Logitech USB Receiver: needs a virtual subdevice
[  1245.968] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:046D:C537.0008/input/input8/event3"
[  1245.968] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Receiver" (type: MOUSE, id 14)
[  1245.968] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[  1245.968] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[  1245.968] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1245.968] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1245.969] (II) input device 'Logitech USB Receiver', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1245.969] (II) input device 'Logitech USB Receiver', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[  1245.970] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event12)
[  1245.970] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1245.970] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1246.000] (**) Sony Vaio Jogdial: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1246.000] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sony Vaio Jogdial'
[  1246.000] (**) Sony Vaio Jogdial: always reports core events
[  1246.001] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[  1246.001] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[  1246.001] (II) libinput: Sony Vaio Jogdial: is a virtual subdevice
[  1246.001] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/SNY5001:00/input/input12/event7"
[  1246.001] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sony Vaio Jogdial" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)
[  1246.001] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1246.001] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1246.001] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1246.001] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard'
[  1246.001] (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: always reports core events
[  1246.001] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[  1246.001] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[  1246.001] (II) libinput: Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard: is a virtual subdevice
[  1246.002] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:04CA:0050.0006/input/input6/event1"
[  1246.002] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 16)
[  1246.002] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1246.002] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1246.002] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1246.002] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Receiver'
[  1246.002] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: always reports core events
[  1246.002] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  1246.002] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[  1246.002] (II) libinput: Logitech USB Receiver: is a virtual subdevice
[  1246.002] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:046D:C537.0008/input/input8/event3"
[  1246.002] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Receiver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 17)
[  1246.002] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1246.002] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  2105.748] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
```

Comment: Are there overscan settings on the Sony? What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` say about the EDID and chosen mode? (Or does it use the framebuffer driver?)

Comment: Wrong comment, delete. Good first post for a new linux user.

Comment: I added the file you mentioned. I tried using xrandr --output LVDS-1 --set underscan/overscan on and they both returned errors (before I posted this question). Not entirely sure if this PC has overscan on it, though. The EDID is shown above, the modeset seems to be 0, and I believe it may be using the framebuffer driver

Comment: If you still have this machine, and you're still at a kernel version < 4.15, you can add a kernel boot option to your GRUB configuration as documented in my (work-in-progress) answer below. I had this problem with a VAIO all-in-one (that came pre-installed with _Vista_), and adding the boot option fixed it up until kernel 4.15.

Comment: And I feel ya—I spent _hours_ with `xrandr` and modelines and `xorg.conf`s before arriving at the solution that I did. Maybe it will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** I'll update this answer once I've found a definitive solution for 5.x kernels. In an ideal world, you would [add a GRUB boot option](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_boot_options_Permanently_for_an_Existing_Installation) to fix the VAIO's brokenness and go on about your day.

---

I'm glad you asked, though, so we have a place to document this for the maybe ten people in the world who are trying to install a modern Linux distro on one of these VAIOs. ;) It's definitely annoying.

Once, in the kernel 4.x days, I had managed to solve it by adding `drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/1680x1050.bin` ([reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?highlight=drm%20edid_firmware)) to the list of kernel boot parameters. (On Debian-like systems, add this to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/grub/default`, then run `update-grub` as root).

Now, I'm trying to achieve the same thing with Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 and a 5.x kernel, and I've got about ten different sites bookmarked, in search of some combination of boot parameters that work.

Some things have changed since the kernel 4.x days. The actual name of the boot option is now just `drm` instead of `drm_kms_helper`, and there was [a regression](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107583) introduced around 4.15 that seems to prevent `edid_firmware` from working correctly anyway. [A patch was committed in May](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=48eaeb7664c76139438724d520a1ea4a84a3ed92) to kernel 5.2, but I don't know if or how that gets incorporated into 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, and so on. As it just so happens, all the Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS)-based distros are using kernels with the regression, and the fix hasn't been backported as far as I can tell.